# как перевести содержимое текстового файла в формат int

Tags: python

Всех приветствую , у меня такая задача , на Python нужно прочитать текстовый файл , записать его содержание в переменную и это переменную перевести в числовой формат (int или float) вопрос на вид кажется легким но сколько раз я не пытался то всегда при попытке перевести у меня возникала ошибка , к слову тот текстовый файл содержал исключительно числа.Мне нужен любой способ как можно провернуть такую схему если это невозможно то какой тип файла нужно использовать чтобы все получилось ?
в текстовом файле было число 100 , и я заметил что на попытке перевести перемнную "cookies_am"(третья строка) появляется ошибка и дальше программа не идет

```
cookies_r = open('cookies.txt','r')
cookies_am = cookies_r.read()
int(cookies_am)
cookies_am - 5
str(cookies_am)
cookies_w = open('cookies.txt','w+')
cookies_w.write(cookies_am)
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "main.py", line 4, in 
> cookies_am - 5
> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'

Comment: Нужно поместить тут коды ваших многочисленных попыток и результаты их. А также пример данных на входе (что в файле) и на выходе (числовой формат это хорошо, но это числа в списке должны быть, например, все в родной переменной, как у вас написано (что выглядит странно?)). И если это учебное задание, то поместите сам текст задания.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функции `int() | float()` и подобные возвращают новое значение, не изменяя исходных данных.
Вам нужно записывать результат данных функций в переменные самостоятельно.

Например:

```
cookies_am = int(cookies_am)
```

Comment: спасибо большое , помогло

Comment: @PanosNegra, если ответ был полезным, его можно отметить плюсом (нажать треугольник вверх слева от вопроса). Если ответ полностью решил задачу - принять ответ (нажать на галку под треугольниками слева). Можно и то, и другое, если ещё и понравилось :)

Comment: `не изменяя исходных данных` int('3.845454), что вернёт?

Comment: @re1von, может, своими словами писать будете? Как-то абзацами комментарии чужие копировать даже без ссылки на автора:-)) немного необычно.